# Does Android support HLS Adaptive Bitrate Streaming

Tags: android, android-videoview, http-live-streaming, adaptive-bitrate

I'm trying to implement adaptive bit-rate streaming in my app that automatically switch the quality depending on the connection speed. How could I achieve this. Is there is any third party library available for this. does the default android video view support adaptive bit-rate streaming?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android supports HLS, please have a look at the Android documentation about [Supported Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#network).

There is also the [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) Open Source project, which supports MPEG-DASH and I think also HLS, which can be used to build native apps.

If you want to use the webview (or support playback in the browser) you could also use web-based players, like the [Bitmovin Adaptive Streaming Player](https://bitmovin.com/player/), which also supports MPEG-DASH and HLS.

Comment: Where in the "Supported Media Formats" link do you see support for HLS? Did they update it or am I missing something. HLS is indeed working but I would like official documentation on it.

Comment: It's listed in the network protocols section. I've updated the link to directly jump to that section. Please note that the use the full name instead of the abbreviation `HLS`, so what you're looking for is `HTTP/HTTPS live streaming draft protocol`.

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed looking for the abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a easy way to perform a player with Adaptative HLS Streaming. In this case Exoplayer has a many advantage to perform this.

If you use Android Studio you can begin with this example that use Exoplayer:

1-Download the project and extract.

2-Build the entire project with Android Studio.

3-Test with emulator or Device

Link to Android Project: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GFXLqb8OdmWG-Kvu2DB4H3rZxv6E2v/view?usp=sharing

4- Touch the button card and play online movie.

I hope can help you!. Good luck